# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" using Spark in Pycharm (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, pyspark

I am trying to write a very simple code using Spark in Pycharm and my os is Windows 8. I have been dealing with several problems which somehow managed to fix except for one. When I run the code using pyspark.cmd everything works smoothly but I have had no luck with the same code in pycharm. There was a problem with SPARK_HOME variable which I fixed using the following code:

```
import sys
import os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "C:/Spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6"
sys.path.append("C:/Spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python")
sys.path.append('C:/Spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark')
```

So now when I import the pyspark and everything is fine:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

The problem rises when I want to run the rest of my code:

```
logFile = "C:/Spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md"
sc = SparkContext()
logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()
logData.count()
```

When I receive the following error:

```
15/08/27 12:04:15 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have added the python path as an environment variable and it's working properly using the command line but I could not figure out what my problem is with this code. Any help or comment is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After struggling with this for two days, I figured what the problem is. I added the followings to the "PATH" variable as windows environment variable:

```
C:/Spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark
C:\Python27
```

Remember, You need to change the directory to wherever your spark is installed and also the same thing for python. On the other hand, I have to mention that I am using prebuild version of spark which has Hadoop included.

Best of luck to you all.

Comment: i tried adding the above line to my PATH variable but still no success. I am still getting the error while executing from eclipse.
My Path variable is like :
%{EXISTING_PATH}%;%PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Scripts;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\python\pyspark

I tried putting spark variable first and pythong second as in
%{EXISTING_PATH}%;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\python\pyspark;%{EXISTING_PATH}%;%PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Scripts;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\python\pyspark

%PY_HOME% = C:\Python2.7.11 
%SPARK_HOME% = C:\Spark1.6Hadoop2.6

Comment: I have done everything from the following link:
http://enahwe.blogspot.in/p/philippe-rossignol-20150612-how-to.html?showComment=1457882166345

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as you, and then I made the following changes:
set **PYSPARK_PYTHON** as environment variable to point to **python.exe** in **Edit Configurations** of Pycharm, here is my example:

> PYSPARK_PYTHON = D:\Anaconda3\python.exe
>
> SPARK_HOME = D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6
>
> PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this problem, it's caused by python version conflicts on diff nodes of cluster, so, it can be solved by

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

which are the same version on diff nodes. and then start:

```
pyspark
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `SPARK_PYTHONPATH` as environment variable to point to *python.exe* file in addition to `PYTHONPATH` and `SPARK_HOME` variables as

```
SPARK_PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Add after libraries

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

and uninstall jet brains products for py