# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o288.fit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, tf-idf

While running a sample Tfidf code from spark 2.2.0 documentation, here is the link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html

this is the code:

```
sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0.0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
    (0.0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
    (1.0, "Logistic regression models are neat")
], ["label", "sentence"])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures",numFeatures=20)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)numFeatures=20)
    featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
    idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
    idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
    rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)
```

While doing this, I get this following Error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-76361218bec3> in <module>()
     10 featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
     11 idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
---> 12 idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
     13 rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)

C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self._fit(dataset)
     65         else:
     66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 265         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    266         return self._create_model(java_model)
    267 

C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    260         """
    261         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 262         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):

c:\users\yash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

c:\users\yash\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o288.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1008)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1128)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF.fit(IDF.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF.fit(IDF.scala:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more
```

I am new to pyspark and I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c) to install it.
Can anyone tell me what am I missing here ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` - looks like Python executable is not on the system `PATH`.

Comment: I have these two environment varibles on the System PATH:

1. C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts
2. C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
@user8371915

Answer (score 2):

I looked around at other posts after posting this question. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255018/java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-python-using-spark-in-pycharm-windows)

I just had to add

```
C:/Spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark
```

to the system PATH variables