# (PySpark) Pathing error: exception in thread "main" java.io.ioexception cannot run program "python"

Tags: java, python, windows, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to get pyspark working on Windows.

I think I have all the necessary files installed such as Scala, Java 8 and Spark.

Unfortunately I am coming across this error when I run `spark-submit`.

I think it has to do with a path problem but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

```
exception in thread "main" java.io.ioexception cannot run program "python" ...
```

[image: stacktrace screenshot]

Comment: You list scala, java 8 and spark... have you tried installing [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)?

Comment: haha yes, I forgot to mention. I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the correct path in your PATH variable ? also your question is already answered over here :-

[java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" using Spark in Pycharm (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255018/java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-python-using-spark-in-pycharm-windows)

Hope this helps !!