# Py Spark No Such a file or directory problem

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to use a SQL table with pyspark. I can see sparkDF like this;

```
sparkDF
DataFrame[SPRAS: string, PRCTR: string, DATBI: string, KOKRS: string, KTEXT: string, LTEXT: string, MCTXT: string]
```

But when I sparkDF.show() I am getting a error. Here is my code;

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
import os

import findspark as fs
fs.init()
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181"
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]=os.environ["PYTHON"]
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().set("spark.cores.max", 3).set("spark.executor.memory", "3G").setAppName('hello').setMaster(
    'spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = sqlContext.sparkSession

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;'
                      'Database=DEP;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
sql = 'SELECT * FROM dep.xxxx'
pdf  = pandas.read_sql(sql, conn)
rdd=sc.parallelize(pdf)
sparkDF =  spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
sparkDF.show()
sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView("sparkDF")
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sparkDF")
sqlDF.show()
```

Result;

```
9/11/21 09:42:45 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 63, xx.xx.xx.xx, executor 2): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\deneme\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)

        ......
```

Do you have any idea about this? (I am new in PYTHON world)

Comment: Apparently, spark cannot access to the python program, see the resolution here (I think it will help you) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255018/java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-python-using-spark-in-pycharm-windows

Comment: Have you already set up the PYSPARK_PYTHON variable ?

Comment: The Spark executors are most likely running on a different host (or hosts) where no Anaconda installation and/or environment exist. The code before `sparkDF.show()` runs locally in the driver program and triggers no remote actions and thus it fails first when `.show()` is called.

Comment: @HristoIliev Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: You have to install Anaconda and/or create the necessary environment on the executor nodes.